# Can JavaFX draw a specified colored bubble chart?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm a new user of JavaFX. I'm trying to draw a colored bubble chart like below: [Colored Bubble Chart Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cy3lZ.png)

I write the following code which can control both bubble position and size

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.BubbleChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class Scatter extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final BubbleChart bc = new BubbleChart(xAxis, yAxis);
        XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 0.1, 0.02));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 0.2, 0.03));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(0.5, -0.4, 0.04));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(0.75, -0.25, 0.05));
        bc.getData().addAll(series1);
        Scene scene = new Scene(bc);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        Integer i = 0;
        for (XYChart.Data<Number, Number> data : series1.getData()) {
            Text text = new Text(i.toString());
            ((StackPane) data.getNode()).getChildren().add(text);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

as the following picture
[JavaFX Code Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7bQD.png)

But I didn't find where I can change the color of each bubble. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: No expert on JFX here, but each node has an `applyCSS` method. You could use this to apply a background-color based on the area of the circle? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#applyCss-- For example `data.getNode().applyCss()`

Comment: Thanks for your CSS suggestion! I find one solution using CSS, let me write down the answer.

Answer (score 0):

public class Scatter extends Application {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final BubbleChart bc = new BubbleChart(xAxis, yAxis);
    XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series();
    XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series2 = new XYChart.Series();
    XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series3 = new XYChart.Series();
    XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series4 = new XYChart.Series();

    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 0.1, 0.02));

    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 0.2, 0.03));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(0.5, -0.4, 0.04));
    series4.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(0.75, -0.25, 0.05));
    Set<XYChart.Series> bubbleSeries = new HashSet<>();

    bubbleSeries.add(series1);
    bubbleSeries.add(series2);
    bubbleSeries.add(series3);
    bubbleSeries.add(series4);


    bc.getData().addAll(series1,series2,series3,series4);
    Scene scene = new Scene(bc);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    Integer i = 0;

    for(XYChart.Series<Number, Number> obj : bubbleSeries){
        for (XYChart.Data<Number, Number> data : obj.getData()) {
            Text text = new Text(i.toString());
            ((StackPane) data.getNode()).getChildren().add(text);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried your solution and find a book explained how to set color of each series and each item. I post the code, check it if you are interested. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.BubbleChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class ColorBubble extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final BubbleChart bc = new BubbleChart(xAxis, yAxis);
        XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 0.1, 0.02));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 0.2, 0.03));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(0.5, -0.4, 0.04));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(0.75, -0.25, 0.05));
        bc.getData().addAll(series1);
        Scene scene = new Scene(bc);
        //// CSS Setting Start ////
        String css = ColorBubble.class.getResource("/bubble.css").toExternalForm();
        scene.getStylesheets().clear();
        scene.getStylesheets().add(css.toString());
        //// CSS Setting End   ////
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        Integer i = 0;
        for (XYChart.Data<Number, Number> data : series1.getData()) {
            Text text = new Text(i.toString());
            text.setFont(Font.font(10));
            ((StackPane) data.getNode()).getChildren().add(text);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
// CSS file content
/*
.chart-bubble.series0.data0.default-color0 {
    -fx-bubble-fill: yellow;
}

.chart-bubble.series0.data1.default-color0 {
    -fx-bubble-fill: pink;
}

.chart-bubble.series0.data2.default-color0 {
    -fx-bubble-fill: red;
}

.chart-bubble.series0.data3.default-color0 {
    -fx-bubble-fill: blue;
}
 */
```

The book "Learn JavaFX 8: Building User Experience and Interfaces with Java 8" explained how to set the bubble color of each series and each item in Chapter 23 "Styling the BubbleChart with CSS". Just follow the instruction, and everything will work.